# Add custom class to all tables created by Markdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

My site's setup: it is an ASP.NET-MVC web app where we are taking documents written in markdown and converting them to HTML to display on a page. This part works great, but has resulted in some unintended consequences.

Mainly, I end up with an HTML page with tables that have no custom class or ID allowing me to add custom CSS without ruining the tables on other parts of the website. So, what I want to do is have some javascript load with each document that gives each table a custom class like "special-table" or whatever.

```
<table class"special-table></table>
```

I found some javascript examples that are supposed to work, but nothing seems to happen when I run it. Here is a JSFiddle showing roughly what I'm looking at, which also seems to demonstrate the other problem I'm having with some really strange inheritance (which only ever seems to happen with tables).

https://jsfiddle.net/LdfL1b30/3/

So, really I just want a way to style my tables without forcing my users to write any HTML inside of their markdown document and without affecting the other tables in the rest of my site.

Comment: During your conversion, can you not add an id or class to your tables? Maybe a post process can insert either id or class. If that doesn't work, why not just target tables in your child element where you display the converted markdown?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the marked-down HTML is emitted onto your page within a designated DIV (e.g. `<Div id="userHtml">` or something similar.  You want the `special-table` class applied to tables within the user HTML, but not applied to tables that are not user HTML.  Is this correct?

If this is the case, you can select all tables within the DIV and add the class via jquery, with code that is similar to the following:

```
$("#userHtml").children("table").addClass("special-table");
```

or

```
$("#userHtml>table").addClass("special-table");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. If you use markdown to add only a block into your page and you want to format all tables in there, have a look at John Wu's answer.

If you use a single/few big markdown-blocks to add the page-content.
And this blocks may contain multiple tables where only some should be formatted, then there is no way, but that somebody (your users?) annotate wich tables should be formatted wich way.

This annotation can be anything that is no valid content. For example the string "special table" would be a very bad annotation, since it might be part of the text.
sth. like

```
<!--SPECIAL-TABLE-->
TABLE-MD
```

or

```
<special-table>
   TABLE-MD
</special-table>
```

wold be way better.
but you could also use sth. like

```
@@special
TABLE-MD
```

IMPORTANT!! Before you choose one of these, you should be aware that most likely, you will have to add additional features based on this syntax and naming convention, and you can't ever change that in the future.

So choose your syntax and naming convention carefully.